# Converting a input-output equation to matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following system of equations:
$$y_1=a_{11}x_1+a_{21}x_2+a_{31}x_1^2+a_{41}x_1x_2$$
$$y_2=a_{12}x_1+a_{22}x_2+a_{32}x_1^2+a_{42}x_1x_2$$
$$y_3=a_{13}x_1+a_{23}x_2+a_{33}x_1^2+a_{43}x_1x_2$$
How can I convert it to matrix form: $Ax=B$ given that
$x = [x_1,x_2]^T$? Do I need to use another $x$ vector, like $x = [x_1, x_2, x_1^2, x_1x_2]^T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know the proper way but i imagine this would be the way to go.

$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{21} & a_{31} & a_{41} \\
a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{32} & a_{42} \\
a_{13} & a_{23} & a_{33} & a_{43} \\
\end{pmatrix}$ $\huge.$ 
$\begin{pmatrix}
x_1  \\
x_2   \\
x_1^2  \\
x_1x_2 
\end{pmatrix}$= $\begin{pmatrix}
y_1\\y_2\\y_3
\end{pmatrix}$

Where A = $\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{21} & a_{31} & a_{41} \\
a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{32} & a_{42} \\
a_{13} & a_{23} & a_{33} & a_{43} \\
\end{pmatrix}$ , X =$\begin{pmatrix}
x_1  \\
x_2   \\
x_1^2  \\
x_1x_2 
\end{pmatrix}$ and B = $\begin{pmatrix}
y_1\\y_2\\y_3
\end{pmatrix}$  in  the form that you wanted.